# Mixed effects machine learning regression models

Tags: r, longitudinal, tidymodels

I wanted to ask you if it is possible to use machine learning in data with longitudinal structure (mixed effects) when the package is in R tidymodels? Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be quite an open question: do you have a specific analysis or data set in mind?

Comment: Hi. Yes, in the literature I have seen that it is possible to use machine learning for mixed effects. For example http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Xiong_Mixed_Effects_Neural_Networks_MeNets_With_Applications_to_Gaze_Estimation_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf uses neural networks with mixed effects. I would like to know if there is a package in R that allows this type of analysis to be carried out, for example the tidymodels package. The idea would be to implement these methodologies in data from bovines with longitudinal structure, which require the use of mixed models. Very thankful.